# Rspec + Capybara: check existence of tag with it's css class

Tags: css, rspec, capybara

I use Capybara with Rspec and have the following code on my page:

```
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
  <ul>
    // ...
    <li class="last">
      <a href="/en/articles?page=2">Last »</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to check in the request that a `div` with class "pagination pagination-centered" exists. I tried this:

```
it "should have pagination" do
  page.should have_selector('div#pagination pagination-centered')
end
```

And this:

```
it "should have pagination" do
  page.should have_selector('div', :class => 'pagination pagination-centered')
end
```

And neither work. How should I solve the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. I should use `have_css` method:

```
it "should have pagination" do
  page.should have_css('div.pagination.pagination-centered')
end
```

Answer (score 8):

```
expect(page).to have_selector :css, 'nav li.active'
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the OP:

Thank you for sharing your thoughts, troubles and solutions, ExiRe - it helped me to find the solution to my own problem.  Though I am using Rspec by itself, and not with Capybara, one of my tests was producing a false negative:

> it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

However, inspecting the html in my browser tells me otherwise:

> < div class="pagination" >

I changed my test to (somewhat) resemble the latter of your initial two experiments:

> it { should have_selector('div', :class => 'pagination') }

And now it passes.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked for me (also using Capybara with Rspec) after trying (and having the tests fail) on earlier examples on this page:

```
    it { should have_selector('div', 'pagination.pagination-centered') }
```